# Filtering out objects from multiple arrays in a JSONB column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSON structure with two arrays saved in a JSONB column. A bit simplified it looks like this

```
{
  "prop1": "abc",
  "prop2": "xyz",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "123",
      "price": "10.00"
    },
    {
      "itemId": "124",
      "price": "9.00"
    },
    {
      "itemId": "125",
      "price": "8.00"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupId": "A",
      "discount": "20",
      "discountId": "1"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "B",
      "discount": "30",
      "discountId": "2"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "B",
      "discount": "20",
      "discountId": "3"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "C",
      "discount": "40",
      "discountId": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE campaign
  (
     id       TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
     data     JSONB
  );
```

Since each row (data column) can be fairly large, I'm trying to filter out matching item objects and group objects from the `items` and `groups` arrays.

My current query is this

```
SELECT * FROM campaign
WHERE 
(data -> 'items' @> '[{"productId": "123"}]') OR
(data -> 'groups' @> '[{"groupId": "B"}]')
```

which returns rows containing either the matching group or the matching item. However, depending on the row, the `data` column can be a fairly large JSON object (there may be hundreds of objects in `items` and tens in `groups` and I've omitted several keys/properties for brevity in this example) which is affecting query performance (I've added GIN indexes on the `items` and `groups` arrays, so missing indices is not why it's slow).

How can I filter out the `items` and `groups` arrays to only contain matching elements?

Given this matching row

```
{
  "prop1": "abc",
  "prop2": "xyz",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "123",
      "price": "10.00"
    },
    {
      "itemId": "124",
      "price": "9.00"
    },
    {
      "itemId": "125",
      "price": "8.00"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupId": "A",
      "discount": "20",
      "discountId": "1"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "B",
      "discount": "30",
      "discountId": "2"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "B",
      "discount": "20",
      "discountId": "3"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "C",
      "discount": "40",
      "discountId": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like the result to be something like this (the matching item/group could be in different columns from the rest of the `data` column - doesn't have to be returned in a single JSON object with two arrays like this, but I would prefer it if doesn't affect performance or lead to a really hairy query):

```
{
  "prop1": "abc",
  "prop2": "xyz",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "123",
      "price": "10.00"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupId": "B"
      "discount": "20",
      "discountId": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I've managed to do so far is unwrap and match an object in the `items` array using this query, which removes the 'items' array from the `data` column and filters out the matching `item` object to a separate column, but I'm struggling to join this with matches in the `groups` array.

```
SELECT data - 'items', o.obj
FROM campaign c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(c.data #> '{items}') o(obj)
WHERE o.obj ->> 'productId' = '124'
```

**How can I filter both arrays in one query?**

Bonus question: For the `groups` array I also want to return the object with the lowest `discount` value if possible. Or else the result would need to be an array of matching group objects instead of a single matching `group`.

Related questions: [How to filter jsonb array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006818/how-to-filter-jsonb-array-elements) and [How to join jsonb array elements in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413861/how-to-join-jsonb-array-elements-in-postgres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your postgres version is 12 or more, you can use the jsonpath [language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). The query below returns the expected result with the subset of items and groups which match the given criteria. Then you can adapt this query within a sql function so that the search criteria is an input parameter.

```
SELECT jsonb_set(jsonb_set( data
                          , '{items}'
                          , jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.items[*] ? (@.itemId == "123" && @.price == "10.00")'))
                , '{groups}'
                , jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.groups[*] ? (@.groupId == "B" && @.discount == "20" && @.discountId == "3")'))
  FROM (SELECT
'{
  "prop1": "abc",
  "prop2": "xyz",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "123",
      "price": "10.00"
    },
    {
      "itemId": "124",
      "price": "9.00"
    },
    {
      "itemId": "125",
      "price": "8.00"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupId": "A",
      "discount": "20",
      "discountId": "1"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "B",
      "discount": "30",
      "discountId": "2"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "B",
      "discount": "20",
      "discountId": "3"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "C",
      "discount": "40",
      "discountId": "4"
    }
  ]
}' :: jsonb) AS d(data)
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.items[*] ? (@.itemId == "123" && @.price == "10.00")')
  AND jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.groups[*] ? (@.groupId == "B" && @.discount == "20" && @.discountId == "3")')
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I just needed to adjust my WHERE clause to use the `@>` operator to make sure my GIN indices were being used. I.e. like `(data -> 'items' @> '[{"itemId": "123"}]')`